# Time complexity for recursive functions

Tags: python, time-complexity

How to count the time complexity for this? Should I count it for to functions separately?

```html
def recursive_function2(mystring,a, b):
    if(a >= b ):
        return True
    else:
        if(mystring[a] != mystring[b]):
            return False
        else:
            return recursive_function2(mystring,a+1,b-1)

def function2(mystring):
    return recursive_function2(mystring, 0,len(mystring)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Big O is the worst case time complexity of how many times your loop (a recursive function in this case) will iterate based on input parameter of size N. In your recursive function, the worst case is that it iterates until a >= b. For an input string of size N, that means your recursive function in the worst case runs N/2 times, for arbitrarily large N we drop coefficients so your function is O(N)